# NoSuchMapping exception while trying to obfuscate

Tags: java, ant, obfuscation, yguard

I'm trying to obfuscate some jar files with yGuard.

The `shrink` task seems to work fine, but the first `rename`
throws an exception.

> Obfuscating Jar C:\work\jars\yguard_temp_8318169257227053930.jar to base_obf.jar
>      [rename] An error ('No mapping found for: Class java.util.Deque') occured during the remapping! See the log!)
>
> BUILD FAILED
>   C:\rms\Setup_FlashAbsicherungsTool_3.4.X_ALPHA2\build.xml:32: yGuard encountered an IO problem!

The log brings no help either:

```
<!-- An exception has occured.
com.yworks.yguard.obf.NoSuchMappingException: No mapping found for: Class java.util.Deque
com.yworks.yguard.obf.NoSuchMappingException: No mapping found for: Class java.util.Deque
    at com.yworks.yguard.obf.ClassTree.mapMethod(Unknown Source)
    at com.yworks.yguard.obf.classfile.ClassFile.remap(Unknown Source)
    at com.yworks.yguard.obf.GuardDB.remapTo(Unknown Source)
    at com.yworks.yguard.ObfuscatorTask.execute(Unknown Source)
    at com.yworks.yguard.YGuardTask.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:592)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1393)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1364)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1248)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:851)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:235)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)
-->
```

Any help highly appreciated. Cannot figure out the reason for that.

Comment: Have you found any solution or workaround?

Comment: Yes, a proper definition of excludes solved the problem

Comment: If your class use reflection then it should be excluded from obfuscating.
Please see here:[https://www.yworks.com/resources/yguard/yguard_ant_howto.html#hints](https://www.yworks.com/resources/yguard/yguard_ant_howto.html#hints)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems the problem arises when you include some class using `externalclasses` nested element while it also happens to be inside the jar (and it's likely that it also has to be accessible from points specified in `shrink` element).